# How do I clear the entire array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a "clear" button to delete all images both on screen and in the array. I am currently using `EZ.removeAllEZElements();`, but that clears everything. Even the sticker palette and background (canvas). How can I delete all placed pictures both from the array and canvas?

This is my code

```
sticker [] arraysticker = new sticker [80];
int image = 0;
int flag = 0;
else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
        && !loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
        && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
    if (flag == 1){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
        sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
        sticker1.sticker11("hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
        arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 1 into the array
        image ++;//increments image by 1
        hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
```

Then it repeats 3 more times with `if (flag == 2){` then 3 then 4. Each flag is a new sticker.

This is my clear code.

```
else if (clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
    EZ.removeAllEZElements();
    //make a clear array
    EZ.addImage("background.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight() / 2);
    EZ.addImage("rectangle.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 7);
    EZ.addImage("hat.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 10, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
    EZ.addImage("blunt.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 3, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
    EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png",3* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 5, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
    EZ.addImage("weed.png",10* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 11, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
    EZ.addImage("save.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 3* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
    EZ.addImage("load.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 4* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
    EZ.addImage("clear.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 5* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
}
```

I am clearing all images and replacing the original images. The thing is, the image with the coordinates are still stored in the array. The clear needs to clear both the canvas and the array.

This is my entire code. Only cut out the EZ.addImage and EZ.addSound codes.

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EZ.initialize(1644,1022);//sets page size
    sticker [] arraysticker = new sticker [80];//creates an array to hold 20 sticker
    int image = 0;//declares an integer variable named image
    int flag = 0;//declares in integer variable named flag and set it to 0

    while (true){//while it is true
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){//if left button is released
        int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); //get x coordinates
        int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse();//get y coordinates

            if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if hat is in the x and y coordinates
                    hatsound.play(); //hatsound will play
                    flag = 1;   //set flag to 1 
            }else if(bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if blunt is in the x and y coordinates
                    bluntsound.play(); //then bluntsound will play
                    flag = 2;//set flag to 2
            }else if(dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if dealwithit is in the x and y coordinates
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //then dealwithitsound will pay
                    flag = 3;//set flag to 3    
            }else if(weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if weed is in the x and y coordinates
                    weedsound.play(); //then weedsound will play
                    flag = 4;//set flag to 4
            }

            else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                if (flag == 1){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
                    sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
                    sticker1.sticker11("hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 1 into the array
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
                }else if (flag == 2){ //else if bluntSound is true
                    sticker sticker2 = new sticker();//creates new sticker2
                    sticker2.sticker11("blunt.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker2;//puts sticker 2 into the array
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    bluntsound.play(); //and blunt sound will play                      
                }else if (flag == 3){ //if dealwithitsound is true
                    sticker sticker3 = new sticker();//creates new sticker3
                    sticker3.sticker11("dealwithit.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker3;//puts sticker 3 into the array
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //dealwithitsound will play
                }else if (flag == 4){ //if weedsound is true
                    sticker sticker4 = new sticker();//create new sticker4
                    sticker4.sticker11("weed.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker4;//puts sticker 4 into the array
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    weedsound.play(); //weedsound will also play
                }
            }

            else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
                //clear array
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");//creates new file writer that writes to save.txt
                for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){//requirements
                    fw.write(arraysticker[i].imagename + " " + arraysticker[i].x + " " + arraysticker[i].y + "\n"); //if requirements are met write
                }
                fw.close();//close writer
            System.out.println("saved");//print out saved to check to see if saved
            }
            else if (loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File ("save.txt"));//creates a new scanner that reads from save.txt
                EZ.removeAllEZElements();//removes all elements 
                //clear array
                EZ.addImage("background.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight() / 2);
                EZ.addImage("rectangle.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 7);
                EZ.addImage("hat.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 10, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("blunt.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 3, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png",3* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 5, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("weed.png",10* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 11, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("save.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 3* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
                EZ.addImage("load.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 4* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
                EZ.addImage("clear.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 5* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
                while (sc.hasNext()){
                    String word = sc.next();//reads next word
                    int x = sc.nextInt();//reads next integer
                    int y = sc.nextInt();//reads next integer
                    switch (word){//switch commang
                    case "hat.png"://if starting word is hat.png
                        EZ.addImage("hat.png", x, y);
                        break;//breaks out of switch statement
                    case "blunt.png"://if starting word is blunt.png
                        EZ.addImage("blunt.png", x, y);
                        break;//breaks out of switch statement
                    case "dealwithit.png"://if starting word is dealwithit.png
                        EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png", x, y);
                        break;//breaks out of switch statement
                    case "weed.png"://if starting word is weed.png
                        EZ.addImage("weed.png", x, y);
                        break;//breaks out of switch statement
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("loaded");//for checking
            }
            else if (clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                EZ.removeAllEZElements();
                //make a clear array
                EZ.addImage("background.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight() / 2);
                EZ.addImage("rectangle.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 7);
                EZ.addImage("hat.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 10, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("blunt.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 3, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png",3* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 5, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("weed.png",10* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 11, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6);
                EZ.addImage("save.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 3* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
                EZ.addImage("load.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 4* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
                EZ.addImage("clear.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 5* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
            }
            /*
            else if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                //EZImage 
            }
            else if (bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                //translate
            }
            else if (dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                //translate
            }
            else if (weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                //translate
            }
        }
        =============================RIGHT CLICK DELETE=============================
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseRightButtonReleased()){
            int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse();
            int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse();
            if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){

            }
        }*/
        }
        EZ.refreshScreen();         
    }
}
```

}

This is my sticker class

```
public class sticker {
public String name;
public int x, y;
public EZImage image;
public String imagename;

public sticker(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    name = null;
    image = null;
}
    void sticker11(String name, int X, int Y){
        image = EZ.addImage(name, X, Y);
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        imagename = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `EZ`? And think about using a dedicated `JPanel` for these images and then remove that panel from `EZ`, instead of each picture separately.